# Actionscript 3.0: Why is it a good idea to detach the code for moving an object from the object itself (eg. Ball and the Ball Mind)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop, object, actionscript

My questioin is pretty much in the title, Why do I keep reading in actionscript 3.0 that its a good idea to seperate the 'mind' from the 'object' when writing code?

Thanks for any help, this is confusing the hell out of me.

Comment: Do you mean separating the "body" (a mathematical representation of an object, which also controls movement, collisions etc) from the actual graphics?

Comment: Because generally the ball's mind doesn't need to know everything about the ball, only the parts necessary to do its work. If everything is intertwined with everything, it quickly becomes next to impossible to make an isolated change without having to change everything else. So, it's considered good practice to separate the ball into into independent abstractions. This is a form of *encapsulation*, i.e. information hiding. This is powerful because it lets you, for example, swap the ball's graphic for a bigger ball, or add 20 balls all with the same behaviour, etc. High cohesion, low coupling.

Answer (score 6):

If you're asking why graphics are separated from the positioning, movement and physics; take this tree I've drawn:

[image]

In the tree you'll see that `Entity` has two properties:

1. Graphics - what the entity should look like.
2. Body - where the entity should be.

Moving down, you will see that there are several things that extend `Entity` - most notable are the `Player` and the `Enemy` classes.

Extending my `Entity` class above, I can easily change what should be used as the `graphics` and also provide slightly different `bodies`. For example, the player and enemies will have obviously different appearances, and the `Tree` class won't need to use a `Body` that deals with values like velocity because it doesn't move.

Here are some advantages of the above:

1. We can create entities that don't have graphics, saving performance and memory.
2. We can use different types of graphics rather than having to stick to `MovieClip` if you had extended `MovieClip` with your `Entity` class.
3. We can add additional logic into the `Graphics` class such as being able to easily covert a Sprite or MovieClip into a sprite sheet for better performance.
4. The graphics will be easier to manage and more lightweight (as opposed to if it were auto-bundled with each entity).
5. Physics will be easier to deal with without needing to know about graphics.
6. The `Body` can be updated without immediate effects on the graphics.
7. Your understanding of physics being completely unrelated to appearance will improve significantly.