# Practical way of getting a picture of a library object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I´m making a level creator for my platformer game on AS3. I´m looking for a way of getting a graphical representation of a library object on my .fla, so the user can insert that object on the world on the desired coordinate. What I mean with this is that I just want a picture of the first frame of the mc, without taking its properties and methods (without the need to make a .jpg containing that image), because that´s when problems begin to appear, and I just want the object functionality on play mode, not the level creator.

Let´s say, for example, a ball that bounces all the time by updating its location every frame. On the level creator I just want to get the ball picture to insert it on the desired location. If I take the whole ball object to the level creator it won´t stop bouncing and it will mess things up.

I hope I´m clear... I just want to know if there is a practical solution to this; if not then I´ll make a class where all the world objects would extend to, that has a init() function that initializes all the object functionality, so it´s called only on play mode and not on level creator. Thanks for reading anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is *adding functionality directly to the MovieClip*.

[Please read one of my previous answers that covers this concept in more depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611426/actionscript-3-0-why-is-it-a-good-idea-to-detach-the-code-for-moving-an-object/9611760#9611760).

MovieClips should be used for the display only, representing the graphics of an actual game class, for example:

```
public class Player
{
    // Graphics that represent the Player.
    protected var display:MovieClip;

    // Constructor.
    public function Player()
    {
        display = new PlayerMovieClip();
    }
}
```

Anyways, once you fix that you can take a Bitmap sample of MovieClips using `BitmapData` and its `draw()`:

```
// Assume that 'mc' is your MovieClip.
var sample:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc.width, mc.height, true, 0);
sample.draw(mc);

// This is your image.
var texture:Bitmap = new Bitmap(sample);
```

Comment: Thanks to your reply, but why use Bitmap where I can just add the mc itself? I mean, because if I do it like you said, the class tied to the library object has no code in it, so I can add it without worries. What´s the benefit of using bitmapdata and bitmap?

Comment: @MatiasMGS Now you're thinking! Yep, you can just attach the MovieClips - that was just an addition in case you didn't want to recode everything to not extend MovieClip.