# How to use addChild() w/o extension from another class?

Tags: class, actionscript-3, oop, flash, flashdevelop

Is it possible to use addChild() without 'extends' from another Class ? 
It's strange, that i need to extension from another classes to use it ... but maybe its my lack of knowledge in as3 ...

Main:

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{
    private var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

    public function Main()
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point          

        var myVar:MyClass = new Myclass();
        addChild(myVar);
    }
}
```

MyClass:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

    public function MyClass()
    {
        sprite.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x990000, 1);
        sprite.graphics.drawRoundRect(5, 5, 500, 150, 10, 10);

        addChild(sprite);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly that you need to extend another class to use it?

Comment: for example, if i edit as: "public class MyClass extends Sprite" and use "this.addChild(sprite);" in "MyClass" it will be possible to use "addChild(myVar);" in Main. What to do to reach the same effect but without using "extends" it even possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

addChild is method that add's DisplayObject to DisplayObjectContainer, so yes, you must extend your custom classes if you want to see it on screen

futher reading: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3e.html
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you're trying to do this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private var sprite:Sprite;

    public function MyClass(container:MovieClip)
    //                      ^^^^^^^^^ Take a reference to a container to add children to.
    {
        sprite = new Sprite()
        sprite.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x990000, 1);
        sprite.graphics.drawRoundRect(5, 5, 500, 150, 10, 10);

        container.addChild(sprite);
        // ^^^^^^ Add internal sprite to the referenced container.
    }
}
```

Where you provide a container to add children to.

Meaning your Main class will simply pass a reference to itself to your `MyClass` instance.

```
private function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);        

    var myVar:MyClass = new MyClass(this);
    //                              ^^^^ Simply pass the main class as the container.
}
```

Another option is to simply expose `sprite` from `MyClass` and then use:

```
addChild(myVar.sprite);
```

In your Main class.

Comment: Though `MyClass` doesn't inherit the "garbage", this solution is a bit of smoke-and-mirrors. The "garbage" is still there when you do `sprite = new Sprite()`. Instead of encapsulating the behavior you're looking for in MyClass, you're applying it to a Sprite. No savings, Net 0. There are plenty of situations where holding Display Objects, such as a Sprite, in a non-display Object make sense.  As a class's behavior becomes more complex, you may find that extending a foundation class, such as Sprite, keeps your logic more tidy, never mind being necessary if you want to override default behavior.

Comment: @Joseph My answer is based on the fact that the OP is a beginner and seems to have trouble understanding that `addChild` is a method of DisplayObjectContainers vs some kind of global method that is only available when extending a MovieClip. As for your comments about cleaner logic when simply extending Sprite, I don't agree with that at all. A Sprite is some graphics. If you wanted to add graphics specific logic in a subclass e.g. some methods to apply predefined colour transformations or whatever then sure; but I certainly don't find it clean to extend Sprite with behavioural code.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611426/actionscript-3-0-why-is-it-a-good-idea-to-detach-the-code-for-moving-an-object) touches on separation of concern a little more.

Comment: Horses for courses, as they say.  I am not pushing for inheritance - I'm pointing out that there are conditions where applying logic to an object vs. encapsulating the logic will make it messier, as in the example.  I saw you were trying to make `addChild` more clear, but the demonstration seems heavy and, if anything, provides a way to continue with the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Joseph You are right, I invested too much in vague code samples and should have paired a solid solution with a thorough explanation of why.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is: no, a custom class cannot addChild without extending a subclass of DisplayObjectContainer. The method addChild() and its related methods are defined in DisplayObjectContainer and only subclasses of it can use them.

You often see the method addChild() used without a calling object (ex: theobject.addChild()) but that's only because the keyword "this" is implied. In reality addChild() is always called by a DisplayObjectContainer instance.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, it's clear for me now ... it's too bad though ... I thought that I could make 'clean' class without additional 'garbage' from extension class ...

Comment: I don't really see what you mean by that. In order to add something on the screen the method addChild has to be called somewhere, are you saying you wish you could add something on screen without calling any method? Inheriting a DisplayObjectContainer does not add any garbage to any class, all you have to do is extends and all methods/properties are inherited and don't cause any garbage.

Comment: all technology that are able to display things on screen are doing it via at least one method call, how is addChild() so different to you?